# tinymce adding a span with id mce_noneditablecaret

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce, tinymce-4

I am using a span inside tinymce, and have added attribute `contenteditable='true'` to this span. In IE 11 whenever i type inside this span tinymce adds following span inside this span.

```
<span id="mce_noneditablecaret" data-mce-bogus="true">﻿</span>
```

is there any way to prevent this span.